# Как переделать на Promise?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

*Есть функция:*

```
export async function login(email, password) {
    try {
        const { data } = await $host.post('api/auth/login', {
            email,
            password
        })
        localStorage.setItem('jwt', data.token)
        return {
            isSuccess: true,
            payload: jwt_decode(data.token)
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            isSuccess: false,
            payload: e.response.data
        }
    }
}
```

*и вызов этой функции:*

```
data = await login(email, password)
```

**Как правильно сделать это на Promise?**

Comment: Зачем? Если для поддержки старых браузеров, то проще воспользоваться например babel-ем

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае переделать на Promise просто:

1. все после `await` перенести в `then`
2. блок `catch` перенести в `.catch`

В итоге получится:

```
$host.post('api/auth/login', {
    email,
    password
}).then(({ data }) => {
    localStorage.setItem('jwt', data.token)
    return {
        isSuccess: true,
        payload: jwt_decode(data.token)
    }
}).catch(e => {
    return {
        isSuccess: false,
        payload: e.response.data
    }
})
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124429/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy----promise).